# Unexpected mouseover on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, mouseover

I have a div(divA) and 1 div children(divB). I have added a mouseover to the outer big div(divA).

Now, when my mouseover on divB. It fires the mouseover event which is expected.

But when my mouse keeps on the same places(or press space to hide that cursor) and then remove divB and replace with divC(another div). It will fire again the mouseover(which is unexpected)

On the chrome, it won't fire the 2nd mouseover event when changing the dom stuff. But on the firefox, it will dispatch 2 mouseover event.

So my questions are

1. what are the expected behaviour on mouseover when dom change(another div replaces the original one) without the mouse move? So mouseover event suppose to fire when dom change or mouse position change?
2. On the firefox, the cursor is invisible but it seems the mouse exists, right? So what will happen if i do a css3 animation changing the position, it will automatically fire mouseover event when the hidden cursor on each element without moving the mouse?

Thanks

Comment: you mean jsfiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/h0269g7n/

If you mouseover divB, and then wait a few second without any mouseover, divB is replaced with divC.

On firefox, it will dispatch mouseover but on chrome, it won't.

Comment: In my testing Chrome also fired the mouseover event, but it was sometimes significantly delayed. Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: i have no delay...it shows the event quickly..